# How to get mp3 file from hls(m3u8) using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mp3, m3u8, hls.js

I want to get the mp3 file from hls using Javascript.

This is my code

```
const https = require('https');
const downloader = require('m3u8_multi_downloader');

var url ="https://cf-hls-media.sndcdn.com/playlist/m40r0aTezpQY.128.mp3/playlist.m3u8?{MAYBE_TOKENS_HERE}"

    https.get(url, (res, extra) => {
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            let hls = JSON.parse(chunk).url;
            console.log(hls);

            downloader.download({ url: hls, processNum: 15, filePath: 'tst' });
        });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
```

After running this, I got many **".ts" segments** that I actually work but I can't  combine them in one file.

Comment: Why can’t you combine them?

Comment: @szatmary I don't know how to combine them. Help please

Comment: use cat or type

Comment: I want to use it on web app not a cmd tool

Comment: then just append each ts to a buffer